# Using Terraform with no specific provider version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have Terraform environment that is running on AWS, but I recently noticed that in my .tf files, I don't have any specific provider version like

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "3.15"
}
```

Every time I init my infra, it's running with different provider version. I have couple of questions:

- Can this situation cause any problems in the future for my environment? Should it be static or is it okay to leave it dynamic?
- Should provider version be given at the beginning or can it be given after the creation?
- I ran **terraform init** couple of times for new modules, because my provider version is dynamic, modules is installed with different provider versions. Can making provider version static break some of these modules?

My Terraform version is **0.13.4**.

Thank you very much

Best Regards.

Comment: This is going to be on the "opinion-based" side of question, but you can find the documentation for best practices around this here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/requirements.html#best-practices-for-provider-versions

Comment: @MattSchuchard what does "opinion-based" mean in this context? Yes I know my current config is not best practice but also it's up and running, I want to implement provider version to up & running system and I want to learn if there is any dangerous scenarios or consideration points to do it. Have you ever experienced this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

The main consequence of having an unconstrained provider version is that a future release of a provider could contain breaking changes and you'd then be blocked from working with that configuration until you resolve them in some way. By constraining versions, either exactly or using an upper bound, you can instead deal with provider upgrading as a separate task to be done at your convenience, without blocking any other work you might consider more important.

The version selection for a particular provider is global for the entire configuration, across all modules, and so Terraform will select the newest available version that *all* of your modules can support. This does mean that if you *over-constrain* your requirements then you might create a situation where no versions are acceptable at all, because two modules select non-overlapping ranges of versions. That is the reason for [the documentation recommendation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/requirements.html#best-practices-for-provider-versions) about using `>=` constraints for shared modules (constraining only the lower bound) and `~>` for root modules (constraining both the lower and upper bound).

In later versions of Terraform there is a [dependency lock file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/dependency-lock.html) which records the selections made by `terraform init` so that they can be "sticky" for future runs. That means you can then be more liberal in the version constraints you use in your main configuration, because Terraform itself will remember which version was selected and re-use that version unless you explicitly upgrade with `terraform init -upgrade`. Terraform v0.13 didn't yet have that feature, so as you've seen that older version will just always take the latest version which matches constraints, regardless of what might've been selected previously.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I'll implement it